# Clipping features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clip, arcgis-10.3

Using ArcGIS 10.3 - I have a large polygon file that shows slope in 10-increment categories (0-10, 10-20, etc.) that I have clipped to parcel boundaries to show how much of a an area (acreage) in each parcel is made up of each categories' slope. The problem is that after I clipped my slope polygon to my parcel layer it thinks that the very large polygon of "0-10%" slope is still one big polygon instead of smaller polygons clipped to the parcel boundaries. Does anyone know how to separate the big polygon into smaller ones by the parcel boundaries? The Clip tool doesn't accomplish this like I thought it would, probably because the polygons are adjacent to each other?

Comment: Use intersect not clip

Comment: Ah! I thought I had tried that and it didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Intersect](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/Intersect/00080000000p000000/) Tool instead of Clip.