# Clipping layer file with shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3

I have a data set at administrative level (generated by appending csv to shapefile of admin areas) that i want to clip to physical building features (from Openstreetmap). To tackle this i've approached as below

Created a layer file, turned this into a representation then used the Analysis clip tool on that file with the building out lines and reapply the symbology from the original file to retain the correct colours. The problem i'm getting is that the output appears incorrect below is the overlay of original data in colour with building outlines in black;

[image: Desired]

Using the method described this is what Arcmap plots, it appears to be doing something with the data as it plottting different colours on the clipped outlines to the underlying values shown on the original unclipped areas.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think i've just realised the error of my ways, through [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158233/clipping-features) post. I should have been using intersect in place.